# Is this grouping with duplets correct for 6/4?

Tags: time-signatures

Very sorry for bad photo quality, but I hope the notes are visible.
Here, have I done anything wrong with the grouping?!

[image]

Comment: Can you tell us what kind of rhythm is intended in the first measure? How many beats are the first two notes meant to occupy, and on (or during) which beat of the measure does the long note start? Otherwise, all we can say is "Yes, something is wrong in the first measure."

Comment: Is the first measure perhaps meant to be just like the second, but backwards, and with a rest taken out of the long note?

Answer (score 2):

The second measure is fine, but the first one is wrong.  The general rule is that your notes should never cross the "major beats" of the bar.  In 6/4, the "major beats" are two dotted half notes, and so the double-dotted half note that crosses this boundary is needlessly confusing.

Instead, use ties to "restart" the note at the beginning of the second beat while indicating that it is to be held:

```
X:1
M:6/4
K:C
L:1/8
(2 FF z F2- F4- F z | F6 (2 F2 F2
```

The initial duplet in this version also has the advantage that it crosses two "minor" beats (the quarter-note subdivisions of the dotted half-note "major" beats.)  I would personally find the following easier to interpret:

```
X:1
M:6/4
K:C
L:1/8
F>F- F z F2- F4- F z | F6 (2 F2 F2
```

This is equivalent to the first version but also more clearly shows the subdivision of the first dotted half-note.  (The quarter-note duplet also obscures the subdivisions in the same way, but it is easier to interpret since it takes up the entirety of a "major" beat, so I'd be inclined to leave it as it is.)

Comment: I agree that the first measure is wrong, but I think the reconstructive surgery went awry. I'm guessing the OP simply intended ordinary 8th notes, and was mistakenly under the impression that the "2" marking was necessary. I'm guessing what was intended was two ordinary 8th notes (taking up beat 1), an 8th rest, and then a tied note occupying all the rest of the bar except for a final 8th rest. Without confirmation, impossible to say more than "Yes, something is wrong in that first measure."

Comment: @AndyBonner:  Fair point.  I assumed that since the given notes added up to the right amount of time, that the note lengths were written as intended.  But I suppose that it's possible that things went even more wrong than I assumed.  :-)

Comment: I came up with the same notation for the first measure as this answer. If the first two eighths are ordinary followed by eighth rest, double dotted half, then eighth rest... then there is one more eighth note value remaining.

Comment: For some reason when people add music notation in this way I sometimes get a very random series of beamed 8th notes followed by a dotted half which has nothing to do with the question. Any thoughts?

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy:  [It's a known bug in ABCjs on this site.](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3737/abc-shows-up-scrambled-on-first-loading-correct-only-after-page-refresh)  It can often be cured by doing a "hard" reload of the page (shift-reload in your browser or something like that.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm just adding some detail re. @MichaelSeifert's answer.

The first measure is confusing, but the values all add up to a full measure. But because the major beats aren't notated in the OP's example it's hard to read. Below is how I got the final notation step by step from two major dotted half note beats, to quarter note subdivision, eighth subdivision, ties, then finally the duplet on beat one.

[image]

At first all the ties may seem busy on the page, but the point is to visually show the major beats. If you think about beating time with your hand, visually showing the major beats helps you keep track of the down beats you are keeping with your hand.

Given the compound time signature, I would expect a duplet to apply to the groupings of three, for example...

[image]

...I don't mean that is the only way to use a duplet, but it's the basic example to demonstrate it.

But the duplet is only on the first beat and one half. Wouldn't it be easier to read with a simple tie?

[image]